# Flow to Email Author

Tags: email, email-template, flow

I would like to plan a button in my Opportunites page which leads to a flow, the flow will give the user three radio boxes, depending on the option selected this should lead to a Email Author page while also passing off the Opportunity ID (variable).

I believe creating the flow with the options would be easy, but I'm not sure how to link to the email author page and also passing the opportunity ID to it.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EmailAuthor page isn't readily accessible. However, if you want to travel down this path, you'll need to learn about "Salesforce URL Hacking". I do this in my instance of salesforce with an on click javascript button, and I frequently use the page I'm linking as a reference for what all the URL parameters in the EmailAuthor page mean.

All you'd need to do is have your final page of the flow lead to a particular URL, which you'd craft using the following page as a reference guide:

http://salesforcewizard.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/url-hack-revisted-auto-select-email-template-with-custom-button/